# Can amputation of hands as sharia punishment for theft be performed under anaesthetic?

Tags: sharia, punishment, theft

Punishment under [sharia law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia) for theft is amputation of hands:

> [As for] the thief, the male and the female, amputate their hands in recompense for what they committed as a deterrent [punishment] from Allah . And Allah is Exalted in Might and Wise. -- [Qur'an 5:38](https://quran.com/5/38)

This would be a painful experience without anaesthetic.

**Question**: Can amputation of hands as sharia punishment for theft be performed under anaesthetic?

My impression from an [Arab News article](http://www.arabnews.com/node/232529) is that it's performed publicly (as a deterrent) and without anaesthetic in Saudi Arabia:

> Sometimes it can be amputation of hands and legs. “I use a special sharp knife, not a sword,” he explains. “When I cut off a hand I cut it from the joint. If it is a leg the authorities specify where it is to be taken off, so I follow that.”

However, from reading Indonesian news, I learned that sharia punishment should be implemented with "love and compassion".

> A. Mustofa Bisri, the spiritual leader of the group, told the [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/27/world/asia/indonesia-islam-nahdlatul-ulama.html). "According to the Sunni view of Islam, every aspect and expression of religion should be imbued with love and compassion, and foster the perfection of human nature.“ -- [Mic](https://mic.com/articles/131332/couple-brutally-caned-in-public-in-indonesia-for-crime-of-unmarried-affectionate-contact#.OhXOpT9wD)

This suggests that amputation for theft could be performed under anaesthetic out of compassion.

Comment: I think that is not performed under anaesthetic because the whole idea of the punishment is to punish them so if they experience quite a lot of pain, it would be their punishment for transgressing.

Comment: Let me clear some misconceptions first. 1- In Saudi Arabia, the punishment for theft is jail. They will never amputate your hands or legs. 2- The ONLY punishment done in public and I have witnessed is Qisas.

Comment: @Casanova 1) is contradicted by many easily found reports, see [here](https://www.moroccoworldnews.com/2015/02/151412/saudi-arabia-moroccan-sentenced-amputation-theft-pardoned/) and [here](http://www.haaretz.com/middle-east-news/1.631994) and [here](http://www.arabnews.com/node/232529) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UxmBp23W6nc) - I checked the comments to the last one since memri sometimes completely changes the meaning of a segment by mistranslating, but that doesn't seem to be the case here since no one complained; let me know if it is.

Comment: @Casanova About 2) The human rights watch organisation [Reprieve](http://www.reprieve.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/2015_10_14_PUB-Saudi-Arabia-DP-report.pdf) reports a number of public executions for things like protesting, "sorcery", and [public stonings for adultery](http://web.archive.org/web/20151016093605/http://new.spectator.co.uk/2014/06/witness-to-a-stoning/) are also documented. (..)

Comment: (..) According to the Sri Lankan edition of The Sunday Times, [migrant workers are warned about public stonings for adultery in workshops about the Saudi Arabian legal system before their departure to the kingdom](http://www.sundaytimes.lk/151213/news/maids-in-misery-from-destitution-to-death-175044.html).

Comment: @G.Back Wow this all is a big lie. I have lived in Saudi Arabia for more than 20 years and none of this is true!. Stoning?? Really?? Just wow...